# State-based vs. transition-based definitions of alternating automata

Tags: automata-theory, alternation

Maybe this is a naïve question but I'm having difficulties finding the answer in the literature.

*Alternating finite automata* (AFA) are usually defined in modern literature in the following terms. An AFA is a tuple $A=(\Sigma,Q,q_0,\delta,F)$ for an alphabet $\Sigma$, a set of states $Q$, an initial state $q_0$, a set of final states $F\subseteq Q$, and a transition function $\delta:Q\times\Sigma\to\mathcal{B}^+(Q)$, where $\mathcal{B}^+(Q)$ is the set of *positive Boolean formulas* over $Q$.

The semantics is well-known. For example, if $\delta(q,a)=q_1\land(q_2\lor q_3)$ and the automaton reads $a$ from $q$, then the rest of the word must be accepted both from $q_1$ and either $q_2$ or $q_3$.

However, older literature (and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_finite_automaton), btw), often uses a different definition, where an AFA is a tuple $A=(\Sigma,Q,q_0,\Delta,F)$ where $Q$ is partitioned into the *universal* states $Q_\forall$, and the *existential* states $Q_\exists$, and $\Delta\subseteq Q\times\Sigma\times Q$ is a common transition relation. The semantics here is that a word $a\cdot w$ is accepted on an existential state $q\in Q_\exists$ if *there is* a state $q'$ such that $\Delta(q,a,q')$ and $w$ is accepted from $q'$, while $a\cdot w$ is accepted on a universal state $q\in Q_\forall$ if *for all* states $q'$ such that $\Delta(q,a,q')$, $w$ is accepted from $q'$.

Let's call the first AFAs "transition-based" and the second ones "state-based". It's clear that a state-based AFA leads directly to a transition-based AFA. What is less clear to me is how to take a transition-based AFA and turn it into a state-based one.
The only way I can see is by using $\epsilon$-transitions, with additional states for each subformula of $\delta(q,a)$, but $\epsilon$-transitions are problematic since I don't see a general way to remove them from state-based AFAs (is it possible, btw?).

So how does one go from transition-based AFAs to state-based AFAs?

**Edit:** I'm talking about a polynomial translation, without determinizing to a DFA first (which is trivially a state-based AFA as Emil mentioned in the comments).

Comment: I don’t see a direct way other than by using $\epsilon$-transitions, as you described. Ultimately, all these models are equivalent to DFA, so if you don’t want $\epsilon$-transitions, convert the automaton to an equivalent DFA, which also functions trivially as a state-based AFA.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the question. As you may have guessed, I was talking about a polynomial translation. Afaik the original definition (Chandra Kozen Stockmayer) is the state-based one. Then the literature started to use the transition-based one. Who was the first who came up with the latter?

Comment: Could you kindly point to a literature in which the transition-based definition is being used?

Comment: Any modern resource that I found, see *e.g.* https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/377978.377993 instead do you know of any modern resource that uses the state-based definition?

Comment: Actually, Chandra, Kozen, and Stockmayer (https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/322234.322243 , p. 127) use the transition-based definition, even allowing *arbitrary* Boolean functions. Also, note that the Wikipedia definition does explicitly allow $\epsilon$-transitions (though I wonder whether it would be better to rewrite the article).

Comment: FWIW, I rewrote the definition on Wikipedia now to use the transition-based definition.

Comment: Thanks, that will avoid further confusion!